# I got this error while working with tabs in android

Tags: java, android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.prime.csitnepal, PID: 28301
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prime.csitnepal/com.prime.csitnepal.semesterone.phy.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2756)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
        at com.prime.csitnepal.semesterone.phy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6692)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2709)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Do you know what this:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener
     means?

Comment: The error occurs at line 31 of MainActivity.java. Please post the code of MainActivity